# How to turn `[1, 5]` into `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` in a DataFrame column of list type?

Tags: python-polars

I have a polars dataframe:

```py
pl.DataFrame({'a':[[1,3], [1,5]]})
```

```
a
list
[1, 3]
[1, 5]
```

and I'd like to do some kind of vectorized operation to expand this into:

```
a
list
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

A solution I've come up with is splitting the array into two columns (`init`, and `final`), then doing `pl.struct(['init', 'final'])` followed by `apply` to get the range.

```
def get_valid_codes(struct: dict) -> list:
    code_range = set(range(struct['init'], struct['final'] + 1))
    codes      =  list(set.intersection(valid_codes, code_range))
    return codes if codes else [0]
```

This is slow for my dataset (300M rows) and I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Bonus points if you can figure out how to filter out certain (predefined) values from the lists.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand this correctly now.  In your question's code, you are keeping only 'valid_codes' ... but in the text of your question, you are asking to filter out certain predefined values.  So I coded to the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's expand the data so we can show some logic for 'bad codes'.

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({"a": [[1, 3], [1, 5], [7, 9], [3, 7], [9, 13], [5, 11]]})
print(df)
```

```
shape: (6, 1)
┌────────────┐
│ a          │
│ ---        │
│ list [i64] │
╞════════════╡
│ [1, 3]     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ [1, 5]     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ [7, 9]     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ [3, 7]     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ [9, 13]    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ [5, 11]    │
└────────────┘
```

We'll use 6 through 10 as 'bad codes' to weed out.  And we'll make heavy use of the `arr` subset of Expressions:

```py
bad_codes = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
df.with_column(
    pl.arange(pl.col("a").arr.first(), pl.col("a").arr.last() + 1)
    .arr.eval(pl.first().filter(pl.first().is_in(bad_codes).is_not()),
              parallel=True)
    .alias("result")
)
```

```
shape: (6, 2)
┌────────────┬───────────────┐
│ a          ┆ result        │
│ ---        ┆ ---           │
│ list [i64] ┆ list [i64]    │
╞════════════╪═══════════════╡
│ [1, 3]     ┆ [1, 2, 3]     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ [1, 5]     ┆ [1, 2, ... 5] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ [7, 9]     ┆ []            │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ [3, 7]     ┆ [3, 4, 5]     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ [9, 13]    ┆ [11, 12, 13]  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ [5, 11]    ┆ [5, 11]       │
└────────────┴───────────────┘
```

This algorithm leaves an empty list `[]` when all codes are "bad codes".  If you need a `[0]` instead of an empty list, you can use a `pl.when` and the `arr.lengths` expression to change those to `[0]`.

Comment: I've edited the answer to include the `parallel=True` option on the `arr.eval` expression.  You can try setting this to `False` to see which is faster for your case.  https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.internals.expr.ExprListNameSpace.eval.html#polars.internals.expr.ExprListNameSpace.eval

Comment: Awesome. `pl.arange` was the magic sauce. How did you manage to recall that from the API? Anyway, this is a textbook solution and taught me so much. Thanks!